# When sharing posts on social media (i.e. copying a post made by someone else) do you need the permission of the author?

Tags: copyright, social-media

A bit of a follow up to [Is it legal to copy pictures found on social media and upload them again?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13118/is-it-legal-to-copy-pictures-found-on-social-media-and-upload-them-again?noredirect=1#comment133182_13118)

When a person takes a picture or writes some text, they are by default the copyright owner. Many social media platforms (such as Facebook) have the option to share content created by other people. Would you need the permission of the owner before sharing or is there something in the TOS that allows for this without their permission?

Answer (score 1):

> Would you need the permission of the owner before sharing or is there something in the TOS that allows for this without their permission?

Yes, you need permission and there is something in the TOS whereby the poster gives that permission under a licence, the terms of which are detailed in the TOS.

Comment: Any idea where in the TOS it grants a user the right to use content uploaded by other users? Section 3 covers licensing but makes no mention of this https://www.facebook.com/terms.php

Comment: Section 3.3, "The permissions you give us". The specific wording is: "when you share, post, or upload content..., you grant us a ... license to host, use, distribute, modify, run, copy, publicly perform or display, translate, and create derivative works of your content". (Note that this is giving Facebook the right to share etc. content uploaded by its users, and Facebook then gives the users the right to do certain things with that content, like viewing it on facebook.com, but Facebook does _not_ necessarily give users the right to make their own separate copies and use them elsewhere.)